# how to send different content based on screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to serve different content, based on whether a page
is viewed on a large screen (PC/tablet) or small screen (mobile).
My site is responsive, using bootstrap, but I have a lot of content, which is only appropriate for PC; it completely overwhelms mobile readers.

How can I feed different paragraph and image content when the site is
viewed on a smaller screens?

It's been suggested I use javascript or (worse) media queries, but I don't know how.
I'm new at this - can you provide some example code?

Thx

Note 1: This is not (just) a style sheet issue.  Rather than rendering
the same content in a different format, I want to send different content.

Note 2: I do *not* want to develop a new .mobi site, which will lose
my existing search engine reputation.

Comment: You may want to look into this section of the Bootstrap documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: `worse` media queries? what are you talking about, media queries is the way to go for a well design responsive site, what I would do instead of serving different content, i will let the device decide how much content want to consume, so if you in a mobile you can do a `$.Ajax` call to your server just asking for limit content, instead if you are on desktop you fetch more data.

Comment: Was quoting advice from commenter (Paulie_D) on a prior question:  

"If you are going to serve the same page but diff content then media queries is not really the proper option IMO. On mobile you'd force the user to download content that you aren't going to show them (and vice versa)... not good for performance. You should not serve content that you aren't ever going to show. You'd be better off feeding only the desired content at runtime via javascript."   I don't want this to devolve into a methods war between media queries vs javascript.  Would you mind making a small example?

Comment: @murspieg The advice you quoted is good advice. That said, it's generally advantageous to have the same content on a site, but perhaps presented in different ways. (On a desktop, something might be on a visible sidebar - on a phone, it might be in an expandable menu). If there's a certain need for functional differences (ie, a WebRTC demo that only works on desktop), then this is more of a serverside-language (PHP, Ruby, Nodejs) question

Comment: @VLS / @ Katana314 Will try applying visible- hidden- utilities; didn't realize they were already in bootstrap.

Comment: @VLS / @ Katana314 Works great, thanks for the good advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at this, it's quite similar to what you are trying to achieve: [Prevent a video background from being downloaded on mobile browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31612822/prevent-a-video-background-from-being-downloaded-on-mobile-browsers/31624225#31624225)

You can use this code to detect mobile devices:

```
function detectmob() { 

    if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
    || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
    || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
    || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
    || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
    || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
    || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
    ){

        // If mobile, then we do all this

    }
    else {

        // If not mobile then do this

    }
} // detectmob
```

**----------[ EDIT ]----------**

```
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;

if (width  > 480) {
    // Mobile code
} else {
    // Other code
}
```

**----------[ EDIT ]----------**

Create two files, `mobile.html` and `desktop.html` and give both of them the appropriate content.
Then, in your main page, put the following javascript at the **bottom** of the page:

```
function getFileContent(file) {
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
            if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
                var fileContent = rawFile.responseText;
                document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = fileContent;
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}
```

Now you can use the previous javascript to get file contents and display them, based on whether the visitor is on a mobile phone or on a computer:

```
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;

if (width  > 480) {
    // Mobile code
    getFileContent("mobile.html");
} else {
    // Other code
    getFileContent("desktop.html");
}
```

And that should be it! If you need any further help, please let me know.

Comment: I'd rather go by general screensize, rather than listing every device that's out there.  Each time a new device comes on the market, the code become obsolete.  Example for that?

Comment: I suppose you're right, I hadn't thought of that. I'll update my answer!

Comment: #Daan excellent!  But I don't understand how the javascript interacts with the html.  Where is the paragraph content (within div's in the html?) and how does the jasascript function select whether it's being displayed/delivered?  I'm big newbie on javascript - can you flesh out an example?

Comment: Glad you like it! I'll get onto that part and let you know when I've finished.

Comment: @murspieg Updated again!

Comment: Thanks for the extra details. I might not use this, but I'd love to learn the method anyway.  I must've messed something up (told you I was newbie).  Created mobile and desktop htmls; in index.html, I put your function at the bottom of body.  Where does the `var width` code go?  (Everything I tried just writes the function code to the screen.)

Comment: Have you put the `<script>...</script>` tags around the code?

Comment: Thanks that help.  Now, where does the `var width` code go?

Comment: That doesn't really matter, but just to make it easy, I would put it in the same place as the other code.

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean? @murspieg

Comment: (Ignore that: trying to insert code).
Code still fails; must be missing something fundamental.  
In mobile.html:  
    <body>
    This is mobile  (or This is desktop in desktop.html)
    </body>  
Index.html has:  
    <body>
    This is index
    <script>
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    ...  etc from your example
    function getFileContent(file) {
    ...  etc from your example
    </script>
    </body>  
Tried adding js library (in index's <head>), no effect:
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

Comment: (sorry: tried to format the code with 4 leading spaces, but didn't work.)

Comment: I will try adding the same code you did to a testarea on my server. I'll get back to you asap!

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just stupid... Inside the `getFileContent` function, a variable `fileContent` is created (`var fileContent = rawFile.responseText;`). Later on, the variable `allText` is used. This should of course be changed to `fileContent`.

I've also modified the answer to fix this misstake, please let me know if this helped.

TLDR: In the `getFileContent` function, change `allText` to `fileContent`.

Comment: works like a charm!  Thanks for finding the simple typo.